# No files found for Agora Cloud Recording

Tags: agora.io, agora-cloud-recording

I am using Agora SDK to invoke the Cloud Recording functionality.  Why couldn't I find any recorded files in the cloud storage (AWE)?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find any recorded files in the cloud storage after a cloud recording session, check if any of the following situations occurred:

- No user is sending a stream in the channel, and the recording times out.
- The token has expired, or token authentication has failed.
- When calling the acquire method to get the recording resource, you set the uid parameter that matches that of a user ID already in the channel. For example, suppose three users are in the channel with user IDs as 123, 234, and 345. If you set uid as 123 when calling the acquire method, the recording fails.
- The settings of transcodingConfig in the start method do not follow the recommended settings, which causes the recording to fail. See How do I set the video profile of the recorded video? before setting transcodingConfig.
- Your cloud storage settings are incorrect. Check the following:

  - bucket: The name of your cloud storage bucket, which was created in your cloud storage account.
  - accessKey: The access key of your cloud storage account.
  - secretKey: The secret key of your cloud storage account.
    If you have enabled Agora Message Notification Service, you will receive the cloud_recording_error callback when the service detects that your cloud storage settings are incorrect.